# How To Parse a PHP stdObject

Tags: php, parsing

Hello There I have the following code:

```
stdClass Object ( 
  [num_rows] => 3 [row] => Array ( 
     [product_id] => 2439 [author_id] => 39 [author_attribute_id] => 0 
   ) [rows] => Array ( 
     [0] => Array ( 
       [product_id] => 2439 [author_id] =>  39 [author_attribute_id] => 0 ) 
     [1] => Array ( 
       [product_id] => 2439 [author_id] => 156 [author_attribute_id] => 0 ) 
     [2] => Array ( 
       [product_id] => 2439 [author_id] => 684 [author_attribute_id] => 0 )
    ) 
 )
```

now I'd like to extract the author_id values. How do I do this?

Comment: OK. Have you tried anything at all? Have you looked at the manual for PHP classes/arrays?

Comment: why no attempt at all?

Comment: When you say you want to "parse" it, do you mean you have that as a string of text, and want to turn it back into an object? Or just that you have an object (which looks like that when displayed with `var_dump` or `print_r`), and don't know how objects work in PHP?

Comment: @IMSoP I think he's got an object and doesn't know how to access properties

Comment: @AdamSinclair That would be my guess too, but I was hoping the OP would clarify for themselves.

Comment: Solved The Problem        http://stackoverflow.com/a/26000802/4066062

Answer (score 1):

You might want to [access properties](http://php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php) do it like that:

```
$obj->property
```

Or if you don't often use object you might find this function useful:

```
function objectToArray($obj)
{
    if (is_object($obj))
        $obj = get_object_vars($obj);
    if (is_array($obj))
        return array_map(__CLASS__.'::'.__FUNCTION__, $obj);
    else
        return $obj;
}
```

It converts an Object to an Array.

Answer (score 1):

For your example: `$obj->$row->author_id`

Comment: that was helpful but i wanted to get all the author ids from this obj well thanks for the help.......i already sorted the problem

Answer (score 0):

first of all thanks for all your answers
Solved my problem with the following code

```
 for($i=0;$i<obj->num_rows;$i++)    {
    $array = obj->rows[i];
    echo $array['author_id'];
    }
```

Well thanks again for posting your answers......and sorry for late reply......

Answer (score -1):

$object->row->author_id

```php
foreach ($object->rows as $row) {
    echo $row->author_id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for one of your first posts. You might want to look at syntax highlighting and add some comment to your code.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow Aleksandr. Please add more explanation to your code snippet. This is not self explanatory.